# Starting with Sklearns Nearest Neighbors output, how do I remove results where the record is it's own nearest neighbor?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am want to use sklearns NearestNeighbors() model to do some data analysis.

In my use case, I want to grab the N nearest neighbors and put it back into a pandas dataframe to evaluate the similarity of different records.

However, the results include the original record. In my case, that isn't useful. I want the nearest *different* records.

Example:

```
xtest = np.array([[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,.8,1] [.8,1,1]])
nn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=2)
nn.fit(xtest)
distances, indices = nn.kneighbors(xtest)
```

returns:

```
(array([[0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0.2],
        [0. , 0.2]]),
 array([[0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [2, 1],
        [3, 1]], dtype=int64))
```

In the above arrays the cells at indices (0,0), (1,1), (2, 0) and (3,0) are unimportant.

My goal is  to manipulate this output so that I can create the following columns in pandas:
"NearestNeighbor1" - the index of the nearest record *other than itself*
"NearestNeighbor1_dist" -the distance of the nearest record *other than itself **even** if the distance is zero.*

"NearestNeighbor2" - the index of the next nearest record *other than itself*
"NearestNeighbor2_dist" -the distance of the nearest record *other than itself **even** if the distance is zero.*

In the event of a tie, I don't care which record comes first (as long as it isn't itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

xtest = np.array([[1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,.8,1], [.8,1,1]])
nn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=3)
nn.fit(xtest)
distances, indices = nn.kneighbors(xtest)

df_ind = pd.DataFrame(data=indices)
df_ind = df_ind.apply(func=lambda x: [y for y in x if y != x.name], axis=1, result_type='expand')

df = pd.DataFrame({'NearestNeighbor1': df_ind.iloc[:, 0],
                   'NearestNeighbor1_dist': distances[:,1],
                   'NearestNeighbor2': df_ind.iloc[:, 1],
                   'NearestNeighbor2_dist': distances[:, 2]
                   })
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   NearestNeighbor1  NearestNeighbor1_dist  NearestNeighbor2  NearestNeighbor2_dist
0                 1                    0.0                 2                    0.2
1                 0                    0.0                 2                    0.2
2                 1                    0.2                 0                    0.2
3                 1                    0.2                 0                    0.2
```

Comment: I think it fails in cases where there are a large number of identical records. Like..

If records 1, 2, 3, and 50 are the same, it will put records 1, 2, and 3 in row 50 before it puts itself.  So, if you exclude the first column you’ll end up excluding cluster 1 instead of cluster 50.

Comment: I have added tie breaking - please check out the revised code.

Comment: Do you think that you could explain your use of apply a little bit?

I assume that `x.name` returns the index. I've never seen `result_type='expand'`, though.

Comment: `[y for y in x if y != x.name]` will select all the nearest neighbours except the one corresponding to the index, e.g. if you are on the 2nd line (i.e. the row index is 1) and the nearest neighbours are, say, 1 (i.e. itself), 0, 5 and 8, then this line will return [0, 5, 8]. `expand` is to ensure that a DataFrame (not a Series) is returned.

Comment: That makes sense. I imagine it's more performant than the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for an arbitrary number of neighbors, although, I wonder if there is a more elegant solution using numpy.

```
N_NBRS = 4

nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=N_NBRS + 1, algorithm='brute')
nbrs.fit(X)

dist_n, ix_n = nbrs.kneighbors(X)
replacement = []
for row_idx, row in enumerate(ix_n):
    new_row = [val for val in row if val != row_idx]
    new_row = new_row[:N_NBRS] #Truncate in the event of many exact matches
    replacement.append(new_row)

ix_n2 = np.array(replacement)
dist_n2 = dist_n[:,1:]
results = X.copy()
for col_idx in range(N_NBRS):
    results[f'Neighbor{col_idx + 1}'] = ix_n2[:,col_idx]
    results[f'Neighbor{col_idx + 1}_dist'] = dist_n2[:,col_idx]
```